# external api call in apache beam dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have an use case where, I read in the newline json elements stored in google cloud storage and start processing each json. While processing each json, I have to call an external API for doing de-duplication whether that json element was discovered previously. I'm doing a `ParDo` with a `DoFn` on each json.

I haven't seen any online tutorial saying how to call an external API endpoint from apache beam `DoFn` Dataflow.

I'm using `JAVA` SDK of Beam. Some of the tutorial I studied explained that using `startBundle` and `FinishBundle` but I'm not clear on how to use it

Comment: Is this a streaming pipeline or a batch pipeline?

Comment: It's a Batch pipeline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to check duplicates in external storage for every JSON record, then you still can use `DoFn` for that. There are several annotations, like `@Setup`, `@StartBundle`, `@FinishBundle`, etc, that can be used to annotate methods in your `DoFn`.

For example, if you need to instantiate a client object to send requests to your external database, then you might want to do this in `@Setup` method (like POJO constructor) and then leverage this client object in your `@ProcessElement` method.

Let's consider a simple example:

```
static class MyDoFn extends DoFn<Record, Record> {

    static transient MyClient client;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        client = new MyClient("host");
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        // process your records
        Record r = c.element();
        // check record ID for duplicates
        if (!client.isRecordExist(r.id()) {
            c.output(r);
        }
    }

    @Teardown
    public void teardown() {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
            client = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, to avoid doing remote calls for every record, you can batch bundle records into internal buffer (Beam split input data into bundles) and check duplicates in batch mode (if your client support this). For this purpose, you might use `@StartBundle` and `@FinishBundle` annotated methods that will be called right before and after processing Beam bundle accordingly.

For more complicated examples, I'd recommend to take a look on a Sink implementations in different Beam IOs, like [KinesisIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/e65d457e8ccaddaf291de553bd17e8035ef7f43a/sdks/java/io/kinesis/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kinesis/KinesisIO.java#L603), for instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of calling external system in batches using a stateful DoFn in the following blog post: https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html, might be helpful.